# adding elements of the array and assigning it to the 1st attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as follows

```
var strList=[['attribute','rulelist'],['attribute1','rulelist1']];
```

I have tried the below code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < strList.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < strList[i].length; j++) {

        document.write(strList[i][j]);
    }
}
```

I want to add attribute to the rule list

My output should be as follows

```
[[attribute_rulelist,rulelist],[attribute1_rulelist1,rulelist1]]
```

can anyone please help me

Comment: javascript != java

Comment: Haritha, Is your format always constant or dynamic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array#map` to iterate through the array and use `array#join()` to generate the `-` joined string and `array#slice` rest of them and generate the array by `array#concat` both of the previous result.

```js
var strList=[['attribute','rulelist'],['attribute1','rulelist1']],
    result = strList.map(a => [].concat(a.join('_'), a.slice(1)));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to do but if i got you right :

```
 var str = "["
 for(var i = 0; i < strList.length; i++) {
     str += "[";
     for(var j = 0; j < strList[i].length; j++) {
         str += strList[i][j] + ",";
     }

     str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1 ) + "],";
 }
 document.write(str.substring(0, str.length - 1 ) + "]")
```

this should output the array to the document as a text , is that what you want ?